# query where a substring of an input is a part of the field

Tags: mysql, substring

I am trying to come up with a query that returns a row if the input is either an id or if the input contains the longest alias that matches the start of the input.  Here is an example table of data and what the results should be.

**Table:**

```
id+alias
1 | dept
2 | dept/reception
3 | dept/support
4 | dept/support/server
5 | dept/support/networking
6 | 
7 | news
8 | purple
```

**Lookup:**

```
input => result
5 => 5
dept => 1
dept/add => 1
purple => 8
dept/support/moo => 3
dept/reception/bldg5/floor7 => 2
```

If I was looking for the input within the alias it would be easy enough, but I cant figure how to find the aliases that are withing the input and is the longest alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` 
WHERE `id` = 'INPUT' 
  OR `alias` = 'INPUT'
  OR 'INPUT' LIKE CONCAT(`alias`,'%')
  ORDER BY `id` = 'INPUT' DESC, 
    `alias` = 'INPUT' DESC, 
    (LENGTH(`alias`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`alias`, '/', ''))) DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```